# Bigcommerce - Generating a table for all SKUS

Tags: bigcommerce

Doing business to business transactions through BigCommerce has created a few unique things BigCommerce isn't set up to handle.

One is that our customers want the option to use a page that works like a spreadsheet where they can quickly add products to their cart all from the same page.

I am looking in to the possibility of finding a way to generate a table that lists each SKU in a row with columns for SKU, Product name, Price, and an "add to cart" button.  Basically, run a query of the product database and display the information on a webpage accessible by the customer.

Right now, my solution is manually typing out each row for 1,500+ SKUs.  Hoping there's a better way.